# html table export to excel borders are not showing in excelsheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, excel

I am exporting a html table to excel-sheet.
Everything is working fine but borders in excel-sheet is not visible.

```js
$("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#dvData').html());
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
body {
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-family: Calibri;
    padding : 10px;
}
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color:grey;
    color: white;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}
input {
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-family: Calibri;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btnExport" value=" Export Table data into Excel " />
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="dvData">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Column One</th>
            <th>Column Two</th>
            <th>Column Three</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row1 Col1</td>
            <td>row1 Col2</td>
            <td>row1 Col3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row2 Col1</td>
            <td>row2 Col2</td>
            <td>row2 Col3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row3 Col1</td>
            <td>row3 Col2</td>
            <td>row3 Col3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NitishDiwakar/524ejobf/1/)**

I've tried to change px into em and increasing their size, but they didn't worked.

Note: I am using MS Office 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

May be useful below script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tableToExcel = (function() {
      var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
        , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
        , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
        , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
      return function(table, name) {
        if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
        var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
        window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
      }
    })()
    </script>
```

Live Example : http://jsfiddle.net/cmewv/537/

Answer (score 0):

**Following code with convert HTML table into Excel file with the custom file name and with proper font family**

**Convert Javascript to Excel with Font**

```
<table id="example">
    <tr>
        <th>Column One</th>
        <th>Column Two</th>
        <th>Column Three</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row1 Col1</td>
        <td>row1 Col2</td>
        <td>row1 Col3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row2 Col1</td>
        <td>row2 Col2</td>
        <td>row2 Col3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row3 Col1</td>
        <td>row3 Col2</td>
        <td>row3 Col3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Download Button**

```
<a onclick="tableToExcel('example', 'W3C Example Table')" id="dlink">Export</button>
```

**Javascript to convert into Excel file with Font with Custom File Name**

```
var tableToExcel = (function() {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,', 
    template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
    base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) },
    format = function(s, c) { 
        return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) 
    }
    return function(table, name) {
        if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
            var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
            //window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
            document.getElementById("dlink").href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
            document.getElementById("dlink").download = 'test.xlsx';
            document.getElementById("dlink").click();
    }
})()
```